# How much interaction with an Android device is needed to keep a Google account active?

Tags: google-account, google

I'm wondering about Google's [inactive account policy](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/12418290?hl=en). The policy seems to indicate that in order to keep an account active, you must directly interact with a Google service (e.g., Gmail, Search, or YouTube) at least once every two years. I had hoped that simply using an Android device that is linked with a particular Google account would be enough to keep that account active, however.

Does anybody have any more information on this, beyond what can be found on the policy page that I linked to above? The Google account I'm interested in is listed under "Accounts and backup > Manage accounts" on the settings screen, and, for what it's worth, "Auto sync data" is turned on. Assuming the device has network connectivity for a nontrivial amount of time during a two-year period, is this likely to be enough to keep the account active, even if I never directly open a Google app on the device?

If that alone is not enough, how about if I download the app updates that are recommended via a notification every month or so? Would that count as "downloading an app," per what Google has listed on the policy page?

**Edit:** If it counts for anything, when reviewing the web-based "My Activity" page for the Google account, I see records on numerous different days for different apps that I've used on the Android device, even when these aren't Google apps. There's a particular app that I've authored, which is essentially the *raison d'etre* for the device as a whole, and this appears in the account activity each time it's used. Would this be enough to keep the Google account active?

**Edit 2:** Per what beeshyams offers in the comments, Google states that [signing into the account](https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/updating-our-inactive-account-policies/#:%7E:text=The%20simplest%20way%20to%20keep%20a%20Google%20Account%20active%20is%20to%20sign%2Din%20at%20least%20once%20every%202%20years.%20If%20you%20have%20signed%20into%20your%20Google%20Account%20or%20any%20of%20our%20services%20recently%2C%20your%20account%20is%20considered%20active%20and%20will%20not%20be%20deleted.) is enough to keep it from being deleted. What plagues me is the ambiguity they introduce immediately after, by seeming to suggest, if not quite, that taking particular action after sign-in is also necessary. For the time being, I'll assume that sign-in is enough, and that the sign-in that the Android device does behind the scenes in order to sync with the account is sufficient.

I'd still love to hear if anybody has any better, more definite information.

Comment: Frankly, it'd be perverse if all the telemetry that's being sent back to Google didn't keep the account active.

Comment: @beeshyams In this case, the account does not own any apps on the Play store.

Comment: That being the case, you need to perform activities as mandated to keep the account alive, IMO. Nothing in the exceptions policy suggests otherwise

Comment: The [latest update](https://blog.google/technology/safety-security/updating-our-inactive-account-policies/#:~:text=How%20to%20keep%20your%20account,and%20will%20not%20be%20deleted.) issued this year is confirmimg what I said

Comment: What's confusing to me is that the section of the document you link to begins by saying that the simplest way to keep an account active is just to sign into it. But it then goes on to talk about particular actions that you might perform once having signed in, such as reading or sending an email. So is only the sign-in necessary, or is a particular action also necessary? I'm sure that just using an Android device is enough to cause a sign-in to happen, since it syncs with the account in various ways.

Comment: The ambiguity still haunts me. But perhaps I'll go with that second sentence: "If you have signed into your Google Account or any of our services recently, your account is considered active and will not be deleted." That suggests that only a sign-in is necessary to keep the account from being deleted. I haven't the foggiest therefore why the documentation goes on to mention other actions that might be taken; they wouldn't seem to be necessary.

But, to return to my original question, I'm asking if anyone has any resources/experience that speak to this beyond the Google announcement.

Comment: Huh. That suggests that just linking it with your phone wasn't enough. That's too bad.